# Linked android modules generate unwanted .iml files

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm ussing the usual way to link android studio modules to a project:

```
include ':app'
include ':coretools'
project(':coretools').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../base/CoreTools/app')
```

This works as expected but the problem is that this generates a coretools.iml file in the used module folder. I mean, in the above example a coretools.iml is generated under base/CoreTools/app.

The main concern is that this coretools.iml generated file has references to the project that used this module and it is a nightmare to use the module in different projects by different users with a CVS like git.

The question is: Is there any way to avoid this .iml creation? Is this "as designed" and can't be avoided?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [module](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/module.html) documentation:

> A module is a discrete unit of functionality which you can compile,
>   run, test and debug independently.
>
> Modules contain everything that is required for their specific tasks:
>   source code, build scripts, unit tests, deployment descriptors, and
>   documentation. However, modules exist and are functional only in the
>   context of a project.
>
> Configuration information for a module is stored in a .iml module
>   file. By default, such a file is located in the module's content root
>   folder.
>
> Development teams, normally, share the .iml module files through
>   version control.

As you can see there is a lot of useful project-related information in the .iml files but the documentation doesn't state that you always must share those files though a CVS. If the .iml files are a pain for your development team just add them to your .gitignore file.

Comment: I like to share .iml files. This is not the problem. The problem is that when someone uses a module in his project, the name of the generated .iml file depends on the name of the include directive in the project. So, you can end with x .iml files in the module folder because you imported them with different include names in different projects. Anyway, I think I will ignore all .iml files but the original module name and everything should work. By the way, I expected .iml files of imported moudles to be generated in the project folder that use them not in the original one. This is not sensible.

Comment: Well if you wanted to share them in the first place then why did you ask for advice about how to avoid their creation?

Comment: I like to share original .iml files (one per project) because they share some settings, etc. What I don't like is to share .iml files generated by other projects when they use this modules. If you share a module across some projects (like a lib) why on earth would it have to create more .iml files if the module (used as a lib) has its own? I can accept "by design" android studio does this but don't want to share that .iml files generated because of an user linking them to a project.

Comment: What about this? To enable sharing Android source code and resources, do one of the following:

-Create a new Library module.
-Convert an Application module that contains sources you want to share into a Library module. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html#d643385e196

Comment: These modules I am talking about are libraries as build.gradle states: apply plugin: 'com.android.library'. If this what you meant? The problem is that the newly generated .iml files has nothing to do with the imported module but the project using the module.

Comment: What is the output of the following command in your setup? gradle -q projects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100500/discussion-between-isaaccisneros-and-notbad).

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended just ignoring all *.iml in the library module but the one belonging go the module. Something like this in the .ignore file did it:

```
*.iml
!app.iml
```

being the app.iml the real/original module iml file.

Cheers.